# How to display dotted line with an image at the end?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to show a dotted line that finishes with an image after each div.
Each div will be separated visually by that dotted line: [startOfLine]---------[image]--[endOfLine].

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This would be much easier if we could see what html you're working with. And ideally a picture of what you're trying to achieve; is the line meant to be in the middle for some reason?

Comment: Why don't you use an image pattern repeating instead of designing the line?

Comment: Please also show a [sample](http://sscce.org/) of the document structure you're working with.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code I can only give you a general answer. The dotted line will probably be the bottom border of the div styled with CSS, like this:

```
border-bottom-style: dotted;
```

or

```
border-bottom-style: dashed;
```

The image is then a normal img which will be positioned relative to is original position:

```
position:relative;
top:10px;
left:10px;
```

Of course you will have to set the right number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Tania's answer of a background image that includes the dotted-border is probably the easiest, maybe something like:

```
#container {
    background: url("btn.gif") repeat-x 0 20px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

That way you can control the positioning of the dotted line vis a vis the image.

CSS3's border-image property isn't fully supported by every browser yet, but it's worth looking at (http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image).